# ¿Como hacerun login usando tabla aspnetusers identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identity

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo implementar un método login a mi webapi usando la tabla aspnetusers Identity.

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AuthResponse>> Login([FromBody] AuthRequest request) {
            return Ok(await authService.Login(request));
        }
```

Mi problema es que al consultar por usuario y password a la tabla aspnetusers, el campo password usa hash y no se como realizar la validación alli para poder obtener el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Premisa 1: `Mi problema es que al momento de implementar aspnet identity me crea tablas.` Premisa 2: `No deseo que me genere las tablas` :: ¿Estás seguro que quieres/necesitas usar Identity? Entre más leo la pregunta, menos sentido le encuentro, usar métodos de Identity tiene relación directa con las tablas que el mismo Identity te facilita. ¿Quizás te refieres a implementar tus propios métodos y tus propias tablas para manejo de usuarios, roles y demás?